# Force specific text formatting when inserting text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I like to annotate sources in DOCX form by adding notes into the body of the text. In order to distinguish between source text and annotation, however, it is necessary to use different text-formatting from the original text for the annotations. Is there any way to force Word to use this different style when I insert text, instead of having to reformat every individual annotation?

Comment: Do comments not work

Comment: I am hesitant to use comments because they are separated from the document body (and placed at the end of the document) by the upload review mechanism that I am using.

In other words, Word comments' compatibility isn't global enough for me.

Comment: A temporary solution is to restrict my formatting changes to those that are toggled with hotkeys, as that is the quickest way to change the formatting on the go.